# Searchable select element in React

Tags: html, reactjs, html-select

I'm trying to build searchable select element in React. What is really important to me is:

1. Avoide jQuery
2. Posibility to set one of options as default selected

I have list of options, which now looks like that:

```
<select
    onChange={props.onChange}
    id={props.id}
    className={props.style || "form-control"}>
    {!props.defaultOption ?
        <option value="" selected>Select</option> :
        <option value={props.defaultOptionValue} disabled selected>{props.defaultOption}</option>}
    {props.options.map((item, i) => {
        if (item.id === props.defaultOptionValue) return false;
        return <option key={i} value={item.id}>{item.name}</option>
    })}
</select>
```

Nothing really complicated. I pass onChange handler, id and styles. If i provide defaultOptionValue and defaultOption in props, then it means i need to check this one as selected.

Datalist works great for me, but it doesn't support safari and i want to display label inside my input, not a value, as value is id and label name of the object.

I have already checked react-select, but it's missing option to set default value.

Comment: You can use the prop defaultValue on the select instead of selected on the option.

Comment: You can do this with react-select. From *Further options*: value | any | initial field value. Near the bottom of this section https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select#further-options